# not getting error while changing value of final in flutter..it should generate error

Tags: flutter

I have noticed one thing in a tutorial that it changes the value of final object and working well, but so far I know , final can't be changed...

Than why it is working well with this code..

here is the code

check my commented lines

````
class CompleteProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserModel userModel;
  final User firebaseUser;

  const CompleteProfile({Key? key, required this.userModel, required this.firebaseUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CompleteProfileState createState() => _CompleteProfileState();
}

class _CompleteProfileState extends State<CompleteProfile> {

  File? imageFile;
  TextEditingController fullNameController = TextEditingController();

void uploadData() async {

    UIHelper.showLoadingDialog(context, "Uploading image..");

    UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("profilepictures").child(widget.userModel.uid.toString()).putFile(imageFile!);

    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;

    String? imageUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    String? fullname = fullNameController.text.trim();


// here are the statement of changing value of final object....
    widget.userModel.fullname = fullname;
    widget.userModel.profilepic = imageUrl;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.userModel.uid).set(widget.userModel.toMap()).then((value) {
      log("Data uploaded!");
      Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return HomePage(userModel: widget.userModel, firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser);
        }),
      );
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your `UserModel` class's fields: `fullname` and `profilepic` is final? Currently, you're changing these fields, not the UserModel object (which is final). If they're not marked as `final`, it's only logical for them to be changed.

`final` keyword does not apply to complex objects' fields. They ought to be final too if you want them to never change their values.

If you want to see an error try:

```dart
widget.userModel = UserModel();
```

or make fields `fullname` and `profilepic final`:

```dart
class UserModel{
   final String? fullName;
   final String? profilepic;
}
```

then try:

```dart
widget.userModel.fullName = 'Anything' // this will raise an error
```

Comment: ohhh,,, Uff my concept was wrong regarding final,  I was in wrong that if object is final, we can't change its properties value...but now got it well that I have not set object's properties as final and thats why not getting an error...Thanks dear...